# Oring muliple things in a Where clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression

I have this code

```
private CurrencyConversionResult GetNumberOfCurrencyUnitsPerEuro(CurrencyType from, CurrencyType to)
        {
            ...

            IEnumerable<ExchangeRate> rate = info.ExchangeRates.Where(e => e.CurrencySymbol == from.ToString() || e.CurrencySymbol == to.ToString()).ToList();
            ...
```

I want to change the signature of this method to

```
private CurrencyConversionResult GetNumberOfCurrencyUnitsPerEuro(IEnumerable<CurrencyType> from, CurrencyType to)
```

So, what I want to do now is get all ExchangeRates where e.CurrencySymbol is equal to `to` or any of the `froms`.  Question is I don't know how to write in that in one statement so that there is only 1 database call.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var symbols = from.Select(f => f.ToString());
var rate = info.ExchangeRates
               .Where(e => symbols.Contains(e.CurrencySymbol) || 
                           e.CurrencySymbol == to.ToString())
               .ToList();
```

Not sure if Any can be translated by EF (it does not work on local sequences with Linq to SQL) but you can also try:

```
var rate = info.ExchangeRates
               .Where(e => from.Any(f => e.CurrencySymbol == f.ToString()) || 
                           e.CurrencySymbol == to.ToString())
               .ToList();
```